# How to Identify where Instances of an object are Still Referenced?

Tags: c#, .net

After running the VS2010 profiler with Object Lifetime Tracking in my app, I have this on a particular class :

**Number of Instances**----------**1 418 276**

%Total Instances --------------------- %5.8
Total Bytes Allocated ------- 158 846 912
%Total Bytes -------------------------- %5.94
Gen 0 Instances Collected --------- 5 196
Gen 1 Instances Collected --------54 894
**Gen 2 Instances Collected** ----**747 874**
 
**Instances Alive At End** --------- **610 312**

Gen 0 Bytes Collected ----------- 581 952
Gen 1 Bytes Collected ---------6 148 128
Gen 2 Bytes Collected ---------3 761 888

As you cans see, **half of all created instances** end up mainly as **Gen 2**, and **the other half is staying alive until the end of the App**. [*ha, ha, ha, ha, staying alive, staying alive...* -> *Ok sorry, I could'nt resist...*]

What bothers me is that these instances should have a very short lifetime (It's basically a datafield class - that could be a struct, but I preferred to make it a class to "activate" GC on it).

These instances are created by reading very large binary files (each line being a class/ a record) and passed via a small sized queue by delegate/event to workers that basically just read it, put it in queues (which are *very regularly* dequeued), and then terminate (background workers ending normally). I guess Events are unsubscribed to when workers no more exist.

So, **is there a way to identify where are these references hiding** ? Because if they are not GC'd they ARE still referenced somewhere, but how to tell for sure ? I'm tired of guessing and trying so many hypothesis SO if somebody has more rational guidelines or a fair checklist and/or tools / precise profiler places to look at, I welcome it.

**Complementary Resources to the Answers**
[Visual GCRoot via DGML](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mohamedg/archive/2010/03/02/visual-gcroot-via-dgml.aspx) - Thanks to Richard Szalay
Also, this video [GCRoot Demo](http://www.screencast.com/t/NWY2Njcx) from Chris Lovett is very educative on the subject.

Comment: *Still alive*, not *stay alive*...

Comment: @SnowBear : I knew I couldn't trust the Bee Gees...

Comment: @OffTopic : Ha ! I did it ! I've reached ONE 1000 REPUTATION ! My wife keeps telling me it's not like if they were convertible into Dollars, but still, I'm a happy Nerd anyway and nothing is gonna stop this Joy ! :-))))

Comment: Please share what your problem was. What kept your objects alive?

Comment: @jgauffin : I will sure be posting a detailed case here as soon as I finish my study

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Enable Unmanaged Debugging in the "Debug" tab of your project properties
2. Run the application and set a breakpoint at a point where you want to investigate the types
3. In the *Immediate* window, type:

```
.load sos
!DumpHeap -type <partial type name>
```

This will return something like:

```
 Address       MT     Size
026407c0 53ecee20       16
```

Then you can take the `Address` and use `GCRoot` to find the where it's rooted:

```
!GCRoot 026407c0
```

[Chris Lovett](http://www.lovettsoftware.com/blogengine.net/post/2010/01/15/Visualizing-Runtime-Object-Graphs.aspx) (via [Tess Ferrandez](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2010/03/03/tool-for-generating-dgml-graphs-showing-why-your-object-can-t-be-collected-visualgcroot.aspx)) created a very neat utility that converts the low-level `GCRoot` output into a DGML graph which might make it easier to diagnose.

Alternatively, Mohamed Mahmoud created a [debugger extension](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mohamedg/archive/2010/03/02/visual-gcroot-via-dgml.aspx) that enables you generate the graph from WinDBG, but it doesn't work within Visual Studio so you might want to stick to Chris's utility to avoid installing the Debugging Tools.

Having said that, the textual output may well be enough for you to track things down. If you want information on the output of GCRoot, type `!help GCRoot` in the immediate window.

Comment: I guess we are not in Kansas anymore... Ok then, this is completely new to me, i'll give it a shot. Thank u 4 your suggestion.

Comment: @Mika - No problem. I highly recommend Tess Ferrandez's debugging labs for coming to grips with all this stuff: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/02/04/net-debugging-demos-information-and-setup-instructions.aspx

Comment: I have reached a point where Deep Memory Exploring / App fine tuning is becoming mandatory. A brand new world :-)  MM's Debugger Extension is amazing. Extremely useful. Thanks a lot for sharing that link (along with TF's), I guess it will be very helpful to others.

Comment: I am strugglling with WinDbg... Maybe you could also give me a hand on this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861400/windbg-and-net-x64-assembly-step-by-step-walkthrough-for-hitting-a-breakpoint

Answer (score 2):

EDIT 2018: if you have visual studio 2015+ then the whole process is much simpler: [MSDN tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/memory-usage).

if you want to know exactly which instances are alive , all you need to do is take a process dump with Adplus, that comes with the [debugging tools for windows](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=6b6c21d2-2006-4afa-9702-529fa782d63b&displaylang=en).
(its now part of the SDK download.)

then in WinDBG, use the !dumpheap -type  
command to see what instaces of which classes are still up.

then you can use the !gcroot  to see who is holding that reference.

Answer (score -1):

You can type the command `gcroot`.