# WinDbg and .Net x64 Assembly : Step-By-Step Walkthrough for hitting a breakpoint in a C# source

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, windbg

I am having very hard times using WinDbg to track a simple object reference in a C# Forms App.
I have found a very nice tuto by Chris Lovett : [GCRoot Demo](http://www.screencast.com/t/NWY2Njcx) on using "SOS" in VS' Immediate Window
**Unfortunately, I am debugging an x64 App** and recompiling my App into 32-bit will bias the test conditions I am willing to recreate. 
Trying to load SOS in an x64 Assembly results, as expected, in the following error :
`Error during command: extension C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\sos.dll could not load (error 193)`

So, as WinDbg seems to manage x64, that's the way to go for me.
 However, getting it to work with managed code is not a straightforward task.
Putting a simple breakpoint into the attached source results, unsurprisingly, into the following error : 
`Unable to insert breakpoint 0 at 00000000 010e000f, Win32 error 0n998`
`"Invalid access to memory location."`
This is consistent with the guidelines given by Naveen Srinivasan.on his [Blog](http://naveensrinivasan.com/2010/03/10/debugging-net-framework-source-code-within-windbg/) 
However, when I try to use the ” sxe ld” / “.loadby sos” / ”.load sosex" workarounds suggested in that same web page, I get the following error : 
`The call to LoadLibrary(sos) failed, Win32 error 0n2`
`The system cannot find the file specified.`

So I guess the latter commands are also SOS-related

I have also tried to follow an older post from [Eran Sandler](http://dotnetdebug.net/2005/06/08/setting-a-breakpoint-in-windbg-for-managed-code/) which explains exactly how to proceed to set a breakpoint in WinDbg for Managed Code. But I am suspecting the name2ee command he is using to be "SOS" specific, thus making it rather unusable in my case (I am getting same kind of LoadLibrary error).

I am really confused and helpless here. I feel I am bumping on walls whatever direction I take. I am two inches far from giving up and recompiling the whole App into 32-bit to debug it, as I've already lost almost 2 working days on this.

*All this is only the first step towards what I want to achieve, which is to track all the references to a "Trackee" object in a more complex App, using gcroot.*

Than you for your help.

*Dummy Sample code : DebugTest.cs :*

```
namespace DebugTest
{    
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        String Trackee;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Trackee = "Where is Charlie";
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = Trackee; // << Trying to put a breakpoint here
        }
    }
}
```

**ANSWER : Walkthrough**

**1 -** "loadby sos.dll clr" makes it possible to call all SOS stuff. (including "name2ee" command to follow Eran Sandler's steps.)
**2 -** The following command puts a breakpoint efficiently into the Managed code of some method. Example: 
`!bpmd DebugTEst.exe DebugTest.Form1.button1_Click`
**3 -** I am still unable to have a real visual debugger behavior as break point is hit logically as shown in the command window, but not visually in source window.
**4 -** By affecting to Trackee a specific Type (*MyString, for ex.*) I was able to track the Object's adress using 
 `!DumpHeap -type myString`
which give the following ouput :

```
  Address               MT              Size
0000000002bd33e0 000007ff000581d0       24
```

**5 -** Then after performing a `load vgcroot` and `!vgcroot 0000000002bd33e0 C:\graph.dgml` I was able to find and visualize all the references to my Trackee.

Comment: Have you tried ".loadby sos.dll clr" to load SOS?

Comment: @Iridium : Hooray ! I am finally getting hex output stuff I can't understand :-) So What does the CLR trick do ? And what to do next to put breakpoints and track the "Trackee" object references ? I Now managed to follow the Eran Sandler post, But I'm getting an Acces Viloation error at the last step

Comment: The "trick" is simple: loadby sos.dll clr means. Load the sos.dll from the same directory from where the process has clr.dll loaded. No magic.

Comment: Well, I agree, but this seems to contradict the x64 Section of this Blog : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/09/30/the-immediate-window-running-windbg-and-sos-son-of-strike-commands-vstiptool0097.aspx an others, saying that SOS is not x64 friendly. That's confusing.

Comment: Mika, answers really belong in the answer section having the answer embedded in your question makes it harder to find and participate. You are allowed to answer your own question, but are strongly encouraged to give other a fair chance first.

Comment: @Mika: SOS is available for both x86 and x64. Look in the `framework` and `framework64` directories of your .NET installation.

Comment: @Mika: Unfortunately the current version of WinDbg/SOS has very limited support for source file debugging of managed code.

Comment: If you move a copy of SOS into your WinDbg folder you can just type .load SOS from then onwards.